# Can't load audio - "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. - Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, flash, firefox

If anyone could help me out on this error happening in production that would be great.

I've recently moved over the site to ec2 from Heroku.

In firefox the audio now refuses to load.

http://www.earbits.com

But if you view it on the old heroku server the audio does load

http://earbits-web1.herokuapp.com/

I assume it's something to do with cross domain issues, the code base hasn't changed.

Comment: only in firefox you got the problem?

Comment: Yep, all the other browsers work